# Different list in each thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

Let's say I have 5 different lists with stuff (list1, list2, list3, list4, list5). How can I make each thread take a different list as parameter? I've seen a few different ways to call threads but none of them uses different parameters

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Bit of terminology: You don't _call_ threads. You "start" or "launch" a thread, and the thread calls the functions that you wrote for it.

Comment: Re, "...different ways...none of them uses different parameters." How about `threading.Thread(target=..., args=(...))` ? The ... in the `args` tuple will be supplied as positional arguments to the `target` function. You can also supply a `kwargs=...` argument. I'll leave the details of that as an exercise for the reader

Answer (score -1):

You can declare all lists globally and then and use them in each thread by accessing that global variable. Also other functions can make changes to it by accessing that variable.

Comment: Using global variables is a recipe for disaster. There are better ways!

Comment: @JohanL i dont think so, i would love to know other better ways!

Comment: You could just pass the list as an input parameter to your thread, for one thing: `threading.Thread(target=..., args=(...,...))`.

Comment: @JohanL Yes I know this, i think he was facing problems doing this, so did I suggested that way!

Comment: What make you think that? And what could the issues with that be?

Comment: I was using your way @JohanL "threading.Thread(target=..., args=(...,...)"  and my script is working, but I have 2 problems. Firstly my script looks like a 10 yo wrote it cause I'm using this 10 times :D. Secondly my script crashes(or does nothing) after a while.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I have worked on big projects, both of methods have proved me helpful. You never know what can be the correct way untill you try yourself!

Comment: @JenilDave could you please give an example of how to do the global vars and the accessing?

Comment: @Deadmeat check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function/423596#423596

Comment: @JenilDave Ok, cool. Now let's say i made 2 global lists, and created 2 threads. How does the thread recognizes what list to use? I mean how do you tell "If you are thread 1 use list1, else use list2"?